# Github Actions - Write access to repository is not granted

Tags: github, github-actions, access-token, github-secret

### The problem

I have a private repository that I am trying to add python-semantic-release to the GitHub Actions.

When trying to increment the version number, I am getting the error that I don't have write access to the repository. I have used the Github Classic PAT and Fine grained PAT and both don't work. I gave **all** repo permissions just to ensure that I wasn't messing anything up.

I also echoed my my secrets.TOKEN in GitHub Actions to make sure that they were being called properly as well.

**Why am I getting a write error even though I have generated the access token with ALL permissions to to the repository?**

main.yml

```yaml
name: Semantic Release

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  release:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    concurrency: release

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          fetch-depth: 0
      - name: Step 1 - Echo out a GitHub Actions Secret to the logs
        run: |
          echo "The GitHub Action Secret will be masked:  "
          echo ${{ secrets.TOKEN }}
          echo "Trick to echo GitHub Actions Secret:  "
          echo ${{secrets.TOKEN}} | sed 's/./& /g'
          echo ${{secrets.USERNAME}} | sed 's/./& /g'
      - name: Print repository URL
        run: |
          echo $(git remote get-url origin)
      - name: Python Semantic Release
        uses: relekang/python-semantic-release@master
        with:
          github_token: ${{ secrets.TOKEN }}
          repository_username: __token__
```

pyproject.toml

```ini
[tool.semantic_release]
version_variable = "setup.py:__version__"
branch = "main"
upload_to_repository = false
```

setup.py

```py
from setuptools import setup

__version__ = "1.0.1"

setup(
   name="pmp-otk",
   version=__version__,
   # And so on...!!!!!!
)
```

debug log

```
debug: * We fixed the damn bug ([`6d6667a`](https://github.com/***/pmp-otk-sandbox/commit/6d6667afde48fbd3cbdabaa048989379b7216ea9))')
warning: Changelog file not found: /github/workspace/CHANGELOG.md - creating it.
debug: update_additional_files()
Bumping with a patch version to 1.0.2
debug: set_new_version('1.0.2')
debug: Writing new version number: path=PosixPath('setup.py') pattern='__version__ *[:=] *["\\\'](\\d+\\.\\d+\\.\\d+(-beta\\.\\d+)?)["\\\']' num_matches=1
debug: set_new_version -> True
debug: commit_new_version('1.0.2')
debug: commit_new_version -> [main [64](https://github.com/shawnesquivel/pmp-otk-sandbox/actions/runs/4018206730/jobs/6903535852#step:6:65)d5a24] 1.0.2
debug:  2 files changed, 8 insertions(+), 1 deletion(-)
debug:  create mode 100644 CHANGELOG.md
debug: tag_new_version('1.0.2')
debug: tag_new_version -> 
Pushing new version
debug: get_hvcs()
debug: get_hvcs -> <class 'semantic_release.hvcs.Github'>
debug: get_hvcs()
debug: get_hvcs -> <class 'semantic_release.hvcs.Github'>
debug: push_new_version(, auth_token='***', owner='***', name='pmp-otk-sandbox', branch=main, domain='github.com')
error: Cmd('git') failed due to: exit code(128)
error:   cmdline: git push ***github.com/***/pmp-otk-sandbox.git main
error:   stderr: 'remote: Write access to repository not granted.
error: fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/***/pmp-otk-sandbox.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403'
```

### Expected behavior

I expected to increment the version, and to not have and write access issues.

### Additional context

Example commit:

```bash
git commit -m "fix: we fixed the damn bug"
```

Comment: Under your repo Settings > Actions > General, is "Workflow permissions" set to "Read and write permissions"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Go to your repository setting `Actions` -> `General`, then make sure `Actions permissions` is set to `Allow`, and make sure `Workflow permissions` is set to `Read and write permissions`.

If that is grayed out, go to your organization settings `Actions` -> `General`, it will have similar settings there.

Also, make sure to set the following permission in your yaml file:

```
permissions:
  contents: write
```

Write implies read and write permission.